# LiveData is duplicating MutableList

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I want to update my Recyclerview items whenever there is a data change in Firestore.
So my activity have the following code:

```
taskViewModel.fetchedTaskLiveData.observe(
   this, Observer {
    if (it != null) {
     todoListAdapter.setListData(it)
     showRecyclerView()
   }
```

Inside adapter setListData method:

```
fun setListData(data: MutableList<Todo>) {
        //this.todoList.clear()
        this.todoList.addAll(data)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

In this situation, whenever a changed list is fetched, Recyclerview is duplicating and adding the changed 
list below the old list.

And if "this.todoList.clear()" is uncommented, list is getting cleared and no data is showing on data change.

I tried all possible solutions, but I think somewhere am missing a part. stuck since a long time.
Thanks a lot for all kind of suggestion.

Comment: I'd recommend `this.todoList = ArrayList(data)` and then `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Tried. But didn't work

Comment: Maybe your RecyclerView has incorrect height, like `wrap_content` with `setHasFixedSize(true)`

Comment: yes @EpicPandaForce it's currently  height="wrap_content" with recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true).
Do i need to change ?

Comment: Yes. Make it `setHasFixedSize(false)`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Nope didn't work.  I don't know why it is happening. If i put the fetch code inside activity then it's working, nothing is getting duplicated. If i create a repository class and put the method there, then the problem comes due to livedata. As if is livedata is not refreshing.

Comment: I've run out of crystal ball charges with the amount of code in front of me, unfortunately, but at least the `setHasFixedSize` was a good bet.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was stuck with this and found out after 12 hours a tiny change.
I corrected it by changing `for` with `forEach` and that changed the game.

Also I am clearing list items before adding the items.

```
todoList.clear()
```